# Looking for Microsoft Virtual Machine

Tags: virtual-machine

I am looking for Microsoft VM List

e.g.

[List 1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36435)

AND

[List 2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27417)

Can anyone share list of all vm which microsoft provide for Evaluation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

It seems you are looking for something not exactly to be centralized, and not only SharePoint.

As MCT (Certified Trainer) I do have access to all VMs I could use during training, however cannot be shared beyond that purpose.

I could however share one i've found for [SharePoint 2013](http://gauravmahajan.net/2013/01/06/sharepoint-2013-rtm-on-win-server-2012-virtual-machine-download/)

Answer (score 0):

Found Some Interesting links.

- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/search.aspx?q=msvhds
- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36435
- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/nanoserver/2016/01/07/download-just-nano-server-in-a-vhd-windows-server-2016-technical-preview-4/
- https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/#downloads

Non Microsoft VHD

- https://virtualboxes.org/images/
- http://www.sysprobs.com/pre-installed-os-virtualbox-images-vdi-downloads-free-vdi-downloads

As per my view most of VM are available. Thanks to MicroSoft.

And also thanks to Marius Constantinescu - MVP and Asad Refai

Answer (score 0):

I found one another link, we can download readymade os images from below site

https://www.vulnhub.com/